# Need help converting apache redirect to nginx

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, nginx

I need to migrate from Apache to Nginx and need some help in converting this rule

```
RewriteRule ^resizer/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) resizer/thumb.php?src=http://$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=1&a=t&s=1
```

I have following which doesn't seem to work

```
location /resizer {
    rewrite ^resizer/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) resizer/thumb.php?src=http://$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=1&a=t&s=1 last;
}
```

Any help on this front is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
rewrite ^/resizer/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*)$ /resizer/thumb.php?src=http://$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=1&a=t&s=1 last;
```